# Fail2ban rule not working, nginx basic auth

Tags: regex, fail2ban

I have a regexp like this that is used in my fail2ban jail

```
^ \[error\] \d+#\d+: \*\d+ user "\S+":? (password mismatch|was not found in ".*"), client: <HOST>, server: \S+, request: "\S+ \S+ HTTP/\d+\.\d+", host: "\S+"\s*$
```

it should catch a log like this:

> 2023/10/30 13:45:39 [error] 21#21: *243 user "sblandjdjdjt" was not
> found in "/restricted/.htpasswd", client: 176.20.18.39, server:
> smartstar.dpsoftware.org, request: "GET /vscode HTTP/1.1", host:
> "smartstar.host.org"

but it doesn't work...

any idea why it doesn't work?

thanks